# Laravel delayed event in queue with model

Tags: php, laravel, events

I have an `OrderStored` event that has listeners:

```
OrderStored::class => [
    SendOrderStoredNotification::class,
    SendOrderInformationToAdmin::class
],
```

Now I need to add an `SendOrderReminder` listener which will send an email to the customer in 5 hours after order creation and only if customer did not paid the order.

My `OrderStored` event recieves `Order $order`. I'm a little lost with it. If I will set `$delay = 300;` in `SendOrderReminder`, it will be fired in 5 hours. But it will recieve the $order. Will it be model which was passed to the `OrderStored` event and then I should pass id of the order to the listener, not model?

Or it's bad idea and I should do it with jobs?